# Selecting a Value from Multiple Tables if they Exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have three tables I am working with.

```
Table A = Training_Requests (title varchar(20), intID INT)

Table B = Content_Requests (title varchar(20), intID INT)

Table C = Projects (intID INT, otherField varchar(20))
```

I am trying to write a `SELECT` statement where I can pass an `intID` and it tells me if there is a `Training_Request` and/or a `Content_Request.`

I am looking for one result set that could either be `Content`, `Training` or `Content and Training`

Example:

```
DECLARE @intID INT = '123

SELECT 'Training' as val,
       (SELECT 'Content' as val
        FROM Content_Requests as cr
        WHERE cr.intID = @intID)
FROM Training_Requests as tr 
WHERE tr.intID = @intID
```

The above would return a result with two columns which is not what I want.

There should be two separate records returned if both a Content_Request and a Training_Request exist.

The result should look like this, assuming that both a Training_Request and a Content_Request exist:

[image]

I cant create a temp table as this will be inside a view.

**Update:**

*Using Giorgos Betsos's answer, I am getting the following error:
`Subquery returned more than 1 value.`*

[image]

Comment: you need to tell your select what you're selecting.. `Select val FROM (Union Query) t FOR XML..`.. or just take off the `Select( ` part and add the FOR XML after the second `WHERE`

Comment: It wouldnt let me not have the select's wrapped in another select. Error was regarding the for xml being invalid in subqueries when they contain a set operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `UNION`:

```
SELECT 'Training' as val
FROM Training_Requests as tr 
WHERE tr.intID = @intID

UNION

SELECT 'Content' as val
FROM Content_Requests as cr
WHERE cr.intID = @intID
```

Comment: May be my mistake for not mentioning I am outputting this as xml (FOR XML) and its throwing an error when using the union inside a view like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @intID int = 123;
SELECT CASE WHEN cr.intID IS NOT NULL AND tr.intID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Content and Training'
            WHEN cr.intID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Content'
            WHEN tr.intID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Training'
       END
FROM Training_Requests tr
FULL OUTER JOIN Content_Requests  cr
    ON tr.intID = cr.intID 
WHERE cr.intID = @intID OR tr.intID = @intID
```